# JPA database indexes are not working properly in latest H2 (2.0.204)

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am trying to upgrade the H2 version from 1.4.200 to 2.0.204. BUt, in my view, the indexes are not working properly.

**Steps:**

1. Create Entity and Indexes from JPA layer as shown in below image.
   [SomeEntity.Java example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4Lz7.png)

2. Default values in application.properties:

```
    spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./data/testDb
    spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
    spring.datasource.username=sa
    spring.datasource.password=
    spring.jpa.show-sql=true
    spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
    spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
    spring.h2.console.enabled=true
    spring.h2.conso\le.path=/h2
```

3. Start the spring-boot application.

> Till this step, everything should be fine and index should be created successfully.

4. Now, restart the service.

> Here, H2 service *( especially,"CreateIndex.executeMeta")* is trying to create the index (custom Index) again and failed.

Above steps are working fine in older versions (1.4.200 and below).

Anyone faced similar issue or do we have any workaround for this?
Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

There have been breaking changes in H2 with version 2.0. Some of the changed behavior can be changed back by using the legacy compatibility mode: http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html

Please try setting

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./data/testDb;MODE=LEGACY
```

If this does not help, you'll probably need wait with the upgrade until a compliant Hibernate version has been released. See e.g.:

- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-14985
- https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-15002

Comment: Yes, I raised this concern to H2database team and they are aware of this issue:
https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/3310

Unfortunately , I need to wait till then.

Comment: Also, ";MODE=LEGACY" will not help, since the issue is in hibernate builder.